Debezium example images: Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found
Following https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/main/tutorial#debezium-connector-configuration. When you try to register mysql against the kafka connect, you get the following error. Using debezium image: quay.io/debezium/connect:2.7.0.Final

albert@Alberts-MacBook-Pro mysql-debezium % curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @register-mysql-avro.json
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2024 21:06:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 527
Server: Jetty(9.4.53.v20231009)

{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter for configuration key.converter: Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found.\nInvalid value io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter for configuration value.converter: Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint /connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate"}%


Can you post your docker image

it looks like the image doesn't include https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter
